# Django : open application on client station

Tags: django, networking

I would like to ask a relatively simple question in which I didn't put much thought in yet. But I'd just like to know if this is possible before starting painful implementations of my app!

Here it is : Is it possible (and easy..) to run an application and communicate with files on the client's computer from a web application developped in Django ?

I'd really just like to know if it's feasible. Of course if you have a few hints on how to do it, they would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to do that. You just need to add a proper URL with its corresponding view, processing your HTTP request from client machines and interacting with local files as you need.

Key thing here is to use a proper HttpClient on the machine accessing your client's file.

Comment: Would you have an example of HttpClient in use ? What I need to do is basically read some files, create files and dirs and open applications on the client machine. I don't really know where to start